# How can I write special character ͻ tilde?

Tags: html

How can "ͻ tilde" in html? What is code for this character?
I mean something like `$ctilde;`

Comment: can you please tell me the script/language in which ͻ tilde is present.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:-

```
 <div>
&#891; &#8764;
</div>
```

Sources :

1. [w3schools.com (ͻ)](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/tryit.asp?deci=891/)
2. [w3schools.com (Ͻ)](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/tryit.asp?deci=1021)
3. [w3schools.com (∼)](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/tryit.asp?deci=8764&ent=sim)